# How do I loop backwards from SiteMap.CurrentNode to SiteMap.RootNode

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, loops, sitemap

I have a simple Sitemap like this from asp:SiteMapDataSource:

Page 1 > Page 2 > Page 3

I would like to create foreach loop in C# that generates it instead for using asp:SiteMapPath because I need to add some exceptions to it. Now I cannot figure out how do I loop backwards from SiteMap.CurrentNode to SiteMap.RootNode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The property you are looking for is [SiteMapNode.ParentNode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sitemapnode.parentnode.aspx)

```
SiteMapNode currentNode = SiteMap.CurrentNode;
SiteMapNode rootNode = SiteMap.RootNode;
Stack<SiteMapNode> nodeStack = new Stack<SiteMapNode>();

while (currentNode != rootNode)
{
    nodeStack.Push(currentNode);

    currentNode = currentNode.ParentNode;
}

// If you want to include RootNode in your list
nodeStack.Push(rootNode);

SiteMapNode[] breadCrumbs = nodeStack.ToArray();
```

Comment: Thanks almost working. But how do I reverse this loop as the output starts from current node and not from root?

Comment: Use a Stack<SiteMapNode>, and Push() each node onto the Stack. Stack<>.ToArray() will then return an array in the order you are looking for.

Comment: Btw, if this has answered your question you can click on the tick mark on the left to prevent the question appearing in the "unanswered questions" area of the site.